# CtrlP: ignore files in subdirectory within a git repo

Tags: git, vim, gitignore, ctrlp

For my repo, suppose it's called `top`

```
top\
  .gitignore
  foo\
  bar\
```

I want CtrlP to list files that are

1. Under `foo\`
2. Is not ignored by `.gitignore` defined in **top\**

If I cd into `top\foo\`, and open vim from there, 1 would be satisfied but not 2.
If I open vim on `top\`, 2 would be satisfied but not 1.

How do I achieve both 1 and 2?

I tried [this gitignore vim script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2557), but it only parses `gitignore` when I open vim in the root folder of a repo, so I can't do both 1 and 2 together.
Same for `let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'`, `ag` doesn't try to go up to the repo root and read gitignore from there.
Setting `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode` as `r` let CtrlP honors `.gitignore` in the top folder, but everything under `top\` would be listed by CtrlP. I just want files in `foo\`.

Thanks.

Comment: What about `CtrlP foo`?

Comment: @romainl This works but I'd have to type in :CtrlP foo everytime. If foo is deep below the project root then it's very hard to use.

Comment: can't you modify the vim script to reccursively search for .gitgnore in parent directories ?

Comment: I set my CtrlP to use git ls-files as it's file lister. This ignores the `.gitignore` files but also looses untracked files. For untracked files I just use `git add` and they suddenly become tracked and CtrlP will pick them up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [its home page](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) it looks like you can use

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = [
    \ '.git', 'cd %s && git ls-files . -co --exclude-standard',
    \ 'find %s -type f'
    \ ]
```

which will have the advantage of honoring all of git's ignore-pattern processing, not just the toplevel positive `.gitiginore` patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is no apparent way to do it, so I just followed @kamaradclimber 's suggestion, spent an hour and made this: [RootIgnore](https://github.com/octref/RootIgnore)
Never coded in VimScript before so it took me some time :-)

You can install it using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim).
It searches upward recursively for `.git` dir, gets the `.gitignore` in the same dir as the `.git` dir, and sets `wildignore` accordingly.

Update:
@jthill's method works better than mine.
But CtrlP has custom search commands while CommandT does not. So my plugin can still be useful to CommandT users.

Comment: I'm coming from the future. Apparently CommandT has [this functionality](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt#L764) built in by now.